# Does using a climbing speed prevent casting spells with somatic components?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I've been using Spiderclimb occasionally in my escapades to climb onto walls and ceilings and cast spells from a safe position.

It never really occurred to me until just now of how that looks or works. But now I wonder, if I'm potentially using my hands to climb or "stick" to walls, does that limit my ability to cast spells with somatic components?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### *Spider Climb*: No

The spell *spider climb* specifically states that the target can climb "while leaving its hands free".

### Climb Speed: DM discretion

Creatures like the Brown Bear naturally have a climb speed, meaning that when they climb, they move at the given speed (1 foot of climb speed per 1 foot climbed) instead of half speed (2 feet of walk speed per 1 foot climbed).

In order to climb a bear needs to use its paws, and similarly, a person would need to use his hands, but it's very reasonable to assume that a person could stop and hold himself with just one hand in order to cast a spell.

Either way, there's no well-defined rule for it.

Comment: A small pick - climbing movement is *not* difficult terrain even though the effects are the same. It is possible to be climbing in difficult terrain (e.g. a steep brush covered slope) in which case movement costs 3 for 1; for the bear 2 for 1.